# Why does this Ruby method need to be a class level method?

Tags: ruby, class

Here's a classic fizzbuzz in Ruby:

```
class PrimeChecker
  def print_em
    1.upto 100 do |fizzbuzz|
      if (fizzbuzz % 2) == 0 && (fizzbuzz % 5) == 0
        puts "fizzbuzz: " + fizzbuzz.to_s
      elsif (fizzbuzz % 5) == 0
        puts "fizz: "+fizzbuzz.to_s
      elsif (fizzbuzz % 2) == 0
        puts 'buzz: ' + fizzbuzz.to_s
      else
        puts "-" + fizzbuzz.to_s
      end
    end
  end
end
PrimeChecker.print_em
```

When I execute this, I get this error:

> undefined method 'print_em'.

I change the method to `self.print_em` and it works. Does this mean it's a class method (I think so)? Was the method "not found" before because I can only call such methods in a class on actual instances of the object? If I wanted it to be a instance method what is the syntax for that? I'm trying to understand Ruby, classes and methods better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class methods are just that: *called on the class*. Whereas instance methods are *called on an instance of that class*. An example is more useful:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    "This is a class method!"
  end

  def bar
    "This is an instance method!"
  end
end

Foo.bar        # => "This is a class method!"
foo = Foo.new  # This creates "foo" to be a new instance of Foo
foo.bar        # => "This is an instance method!"
```

Note that "class methods" in Ruby are actually methods on the class object's singleton. This is a rather difficult concept to explain, and you can [read more about it](http://www.devalot.com/articles/2008/09/ruby-singleton) if you'd like.

Comment: Great, it's kinda what I thought.  Accepted and also +1 for the examples.  Thanks!

Comment: woops sorry, I didn't have 15 rep so couldn't upvote.  But I did accept.!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are completely correct. Currently, the way you define it, you can evaluate the method with:

```
PrimeChecker.new.print_em
```

The reason `def self.my_awesome_method` defines it on the class side is because the stuff inside

```
class MyAwesomeClass
end
```

is being executed in the context of `MyAwesomeClass`. It's all Ruby code, as you can see! This enables you to do things like this:

```
class MyAwesomeClass
  puts "Hello from innards of #{self}!" #=> Hello from the innards of MyAwesomeClass!
end
```

Method definitions will also only work if you call them **after** the definition location, for example:

```
class MyAwesomeClass
  my_awesome_method   # produces a nasty error
  def self.my_awesome_method
    puts "Hello world"
  end
  my_awesome_method   # executes just fine
end
```

Hope this clears some things up.

Answer (score 0):

It's *not* a class method as written; you need to run it with an instance of `PrimeChecker`:

```
pc = PrimeChecker.new
pc.print_em
```

Using `self.` turns it into a class method, runnable with the syntax you show.

It doesn't *need* to be a class method, it's just that that's how you're trying to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Q: When I run ruby.rb I get undefined method 'print_em'. I change the method to self.print_em and it works. Does this mean it's a class method (I think so).

A: Yes. `class Bar; ... def self.foo` defines a class method foo for class Bar.

Q: Was the method "not found" before because I can only call such methods in a class on actual instances of the object?

A: You were first defining it as an instance method. In that case, it is only available to instances of the class.

Q: If I wanted it to be a instance method what is the syntax for that?

A: The way you had it originally:  `class Bar; def foo` defines **instance** method foo for class Bar